# Is it possible to override a method from outside the program?

Tags: python, file, io

I want to change the built-in file I/O methods for any given python application without having to modify its code. Is this possible?

Maybe using Python's `subprocess`?

For example, I want a file object's `read()` method to actually call my `custom_read()` method instead, but without having to change any code in the program calling the `read()`.

Comment: No, you can't change a program's code without, well, changing its code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override module method where from...import is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829200/override-module-method-where-from-import-is-used)

Comment: @chepner Yes you can, with monkeypatching.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626250/494134

Comment: @JohnGordon That's a form of changing the code.

Comment: He specifically said _without having to change any code in the program calling the read()_, meaning it's okay to change code elsewhere.

Comment: @chepner: In general, I don't think monkey-patching is a form of changing the code. However I doubt that it would be possible to change the `read()` method of a Python built-in like a `file` object.

Comment: @martineau you can [override `open`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45950329/5858851)...there's probably a hacky solution that involves writing your own `open`, then importing it, then running the contents of the original script.

Comment: @pault: I don't think overriding `open()` like and monkey-patching it in so it was used for "for any given python application" is possible.