# Mocking python's native `open` function in imported modules

Tags: python, file, mocking, monkeypatching

I would like to overwrite python's native `open` function.
Here's what I have tried. I have the following files in a directory:

```
main.py
mock.py
test.txt
test_main.py
```

`main.py` contains the following:

```
fs = open('test.txt', 'r')
```

`mock.py` contains the following:

```
def open():
  print("hello")
```

`test.txt` contains the following:

```
abc
```

`test_main.py` contains the following:

```
import pathlib
import mock

if __name__=="__main__":
  file_path = pathlib.Path('test.txt')  
  open = mock.open
  import main
  file_path.unlink()
```

In line 6 of `test_main.py` I tried to overwrite by setting my own
function in `mock.py` to the keyword `open`.  Within `test_main.py`
it looks like python will use my definition. However, within the
imported `main.py` it looks like python still resorts to the native definition, such that `python test_main.py` throws the following error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'test.txt'

How can I redefine `open` such that my definition applies to all
imported namespaces?

Comment: If you want to shadow builtins across *all* modules, use the ``builtins`` module. ``open = mock.open`` just shadows the builtin in the current module. Still, it's probably a good idea to use an [actual mock library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just found it thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950221/override-python-open-function-when-used-with-the-as-keyword-to-print-anything). Need to import `builtins`:

```
import pathlib
import mock
import builtins

if __name__=="__main__":
  file_path = pathlib.Path('test.txt')  
  builtins.open = mock.open
  import main
  file_path.unlink()
```