# Recursionerror when attempting to mock built-in open in python

Tags: python, file, io, mocking, monkeypatching

As a follow up to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71450612/mocking-pythons-native-open-function-in-imported-modules) I would like to have a mock `open` function in a separate file be able to use the builtin `open` function. Again, here are the files:

```
main.py
mock.py
test.txt
test_main.py
```

`main.py` contains the following:

```
fs = open('test.txt', 'r')
```

`mock.py` now contains the following:

```
import builtins

def open(filename, mode):
  fs = builtins.open(filename, mode)
  print(fs.readline())
  fs.close()
```

`test.txt` contains the following:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

`test_main.py` contains the following:

```
import pathlib
import mock
import builtins

if __name__=="__main__":
  file_path = pathlib.Path('test.txt')
  builtins.open = mock.open
  import main
```

Unfortunately when I run `python test_main.py` I get the following error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Which indicates to me that `mock.open` is not using the built-in `open` in its body....

How do I mock `open` for `main.py` and all its imports, but have `mock.open` be able to use the built-in `open`?

Comment: You redefined `builtins.open` to an object that calls `builtins.open`.

Comment: Use `unittest.mock.patch` to patch the symbol `open` in `main.py`.

Comment: Replacing `open` with something that not only opens the file, but reads a line from the file and immediately closes it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Here's my issue... I have third party code which opens files without closing them. I need to test this code, and obviously my test teardown can't delete these generated files since they are not closed from within the third-party program. I need to somehow hijack `open` so I can temporarily get my test suite to work.

Comment: The `unittest` library can very much be useful for writing `pytest` tests, yes.  You can use any code you want with `pytest`.

Comment: I use `pytest` to run tests without ever using the `pytest` module.  I don't think there's any reason you couldn't use `unittest`'s functionality in a test that also uses stuff from the `pytest` module, but your test doesn't `import pytest` so I think that's moot anyway.

Comment: The top answer of the linked dupe covers the appropriate use of `unittest.mock.patch` very nicely.

Comment: @Samwise I tried with pytest and renamed the function in `mock.py`: `monkeypatch.setattr(builtins, "open", mock.mock_open)`. Still getting the same error regarding recursion depth...

Comment: As I said, patch it in `main.py`, not in `mock.py`.

Comment: `main.py` represents the client code, i.e. the code I'm testing... I can't/shouldn't be touching that.

Comment: The point of `patch` is that you patch the code under test, from *inside your test*, without touching the actual file you're testing.  Read the linked duplicate carefully, or google `unittest.mock.patch` and take a sec to read over how it works.

Comment: And frankly, you aren't doing this to test the code so much as to work around a known bug in the 3rd-party code.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that third-party code should not be modified until fully covered by a test suite.